# How to get unique combinations between columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Having a table like:

```
F    G
---- ----
123  ABC
ABC  123
DEF  123
```

I need to obtain:

```
F    G
---- ----
123  ABC
DEF  123
```

Comment: are you looking for Distinct?  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: @CR241No, this is not a simple distinct. Or show how you will use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select min(f), max(g)
from t
group by (case when f < g then f else g end),
         (case when f < g then g else f end);
```

Answer (score 0):

This CTE matches f/g and g/f matches (keeps only one match) and unions with non matches:

```
Create Table #tbl
(
F VarChar(10),
G VarChar(10)
)

Insert Into #tbl Values
('123','ABC'),
('ABC','123'),
('DEF','123'),
('123','DEF'),
('123','XYZ')

With CTE As
(
   Select  x.F, x.G, Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)) As rn
   From #tbl x 
   inner Join #tbl y On x.F = y.G And x.G = y.F
) ,
CTE1 As
(
   Select  x.F, x.G
   From #tbl x 
   left Join #tbl y On x.F = y.G And x.G = y.F
   Where y.F  Is Null
)
   Select F,G From CTE Where rn % 2 <> 0 
     Union All 
   Select F,G From CTE1
```

Result:

```
F   G
ABC 123
123 DEF
123 XYZ
```